# Does cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" work together?

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my `OrderSet.hbm` file. It has `OrderSetMember`s as it's child (one-to-many) relationship.

```
<list name="orderSetMembers" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
    <key column="order_set_id" not-null="true"/>
    <list-index column="sequence_number"/>
    <one-to-many class="OrderSetMember" />
</list>
```

This is my `OrderSetMember.hbm` file. `OrderSetMember` has a many-to-one relationship with its parent. I wanted a bi-directional mapping.

```
<many-to-one name="orderSet" class="OrderSet">
    <column name="order_set_id"/>
</many-to-one>
```

Can the parent and the child both be saved with one session-save command?
Or do I need to have another session save to save the child as well?

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(orderSet);
```

These are my data-models:

```
public class OrderSet {
    private List<OrderSetMember> orderSetMembers;
}


public class OrderSetMember {
    private OrderSet orderSet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cascade` and `inverse` have two completely different purposes.

`cascade` tells which entity lifecycle operation should be automatically applied on child(ren) when applied on parent.

`inverse` means that child is the owner of the association. That further means that if you don't associate child with the parent on the child side, the relationship information is not going to be synchronized with the database.

For example, if you add an `OrderSetMember` to the `orderSetMembers` collection in the parent entity instance, but you leave `orderSet` field `null` in the `OrderSetMember` instance, and then invoke `session.saveOrUpdate(orderSet)`, the outcome will be:

1. Both `OrderSet` and `OrderSetMember` instances are saved to the database (`save` is cascaded to the children).
2. `order_set_id` (foreign key in the table to which `OrderSetMember` is mapped) is set to `null`. This is because `OrderSetMember` is the owner of the association, and there was no associated `OrderSet` entity when Hibernate inspected the owner of the association at dirty-check time.
3. When you read the above `OrderSet` instance in a new session, you'll notice that the `OrderSetMember` is not present in the `orderSetMembers` collection either.